# Safely get the UUID of a windows machine?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, adobe

I have an adobe 3rd party tool that I’m selling and I’m using the command line on windows to get the UUID for the user using:

```
wmic path win32_computersystemproduct get uuid
```

Unfortunately, it doesn’t work for a small amount of users who are getting an error that the **file requested can’t be found**.

Is there a better way to find the UUID of one’s machine?
If not, is there a way to modify this code to not throw an error if the file isn’t found? Using try-catch on my JavaScript side doesn’t seem to catch the error.

Comment: It is possible to query in the registry, by the following command: `reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography /v MachineGuid`

Comment: try `powershell (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystemProduct).UUID`

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can’t seem to use powershell because adobe’s “system.callSysten()” command doesn’t seem to support it.

Comment: I got reg query working. Is GUID as reliable as UUID? Is it prone to being changed?

Comment: First of all, as you are using WMIC.exe, there is an alias for `Select * from Win32_ComputerSystemProduct`, so instead of using `Path Win32_ComputerSystemProduct`, you can use the alias `CSProduct`. Then, you can use a WHERE clause to determine if the value is propagated, before trying to output it, and additionally redirect any stdErr output to the NUL device. Example: `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe CSProduct Where "Not UUID Is Null" Get UUID 2>NUL`

Comment: The `reg query` command line results on my Windows PC in an error message that the value `MachineGuid` could not be found in the registry on using x86 version of `reg.exe` in `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` while the `reg query` command works with x64 version of `reg.exe` in `%SystemRoot%\System32` on 64-bit Windows with an AMD64 processor. But the output `MachineGuid` is different to the UUID output by PowerShell and WMIC.

Comment: See the Microsoft documentation pages [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details), [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) and [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys) for more details. See also [Win32_ComputerSystemProduct class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-computersystemproduct).

Comment: If you are using PowerShell v3.0 or above however, you should use `Get-CimInstance` instead of `Get-WmiObject`. e.g. `(Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_ComputerSystemProduct).UUID`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use my [wmiClass.bat program](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10384&p=66414#p66401) version 1.3; just copy the .BAT file from previous link. After that, use it with the standard class name:

```
wmiClass.bat Win32_ComputerSystemProduct uuid
```

... or via the wmic.exe alias:

```
wmiClass.bat CSProduct uuid
```

This program traps the error if the WMI class or wmic.exe Alias does not exists and ends with an error message and %errorlevel% equal 1.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone! I didn't expect so much help so quickly. My current solution (although lacking) is this:

```
 if (isWin) {
    var systemRoot = system.callSystem("cmd /c echo %SystemRoot%") || "";
    var rootDrive = systemRoot.substring(0, 2);
    //var isRootDriveValid = rootDrive.length == 2 && rootDrive.charAt(1) == ":";
    var wmicPath = rootDrive + "\\Windows\\System32\\wbem\\WMIC.exe";
    var wmic = new File(wmicPath);

    if (!wmic.exists) {
        // wmic is not installed or not found
        // Do something else instead of system.callSystem()
    } else {
        // wmic is installed
        // system.callSystem("wmic path win32_computersystemproduct get uuid");
    }
    
}
```

I have tested this with multiple users and it solved the issue for them. I could verify using this method that WMIC.exe was missing on their machine.

However it's worth noting that I barley know anything when it comes to the command line, so please read the comments as they provided a lot of in depth solutions that I will keep trying to learn.

As Mofi mentioned in the comments, callSystem() didn't like me using %SystemRoot%, so I'm first getting it using echo (Is there a better way?). It seems to work, but if someone wants to expand on my lack of knowledge on the topic please do.

Much love.

Comment: There is also the environment variable `SystemDrive` as it can be seen on opening a command prompt window and running the command `set`. See also the list of predefined [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows). However, it does not make sense to get the full path to the Windows directory which could be also `D:\Win10`, get the first two characters (drive letter and colon) and concatenate it with `\\Windows\\System32\\wbem\\WMIC.exe`? Why is not used `var wmicPath = systemRoot + "\\System32\\wbem\\WMIC.exe";` as that would be always correct?

Comment: The Adobe [JavaScript Tools Guide | The ExtendScript Toolkit](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/scripting/estk/javascript_tools_guide.pdf) explains on page 219 the usage of `$.getenv (envname)` to get the string value of an environment variable. Why is not used `$.getenv(SystemRoot)` to get the full path to Windows directory directly without running `cmd.exe` in background?

Comment: Why is the already successfully determined fully qualified file name of `wmic` not used on finally running it? If the __local__ environment variable `PATH` does not contain `%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem` as it does by default since Windows XP, the command will fail although `wmic.exe` is indeed installed where it should be by default. There are users who corrupt their __system__ environment variable `Path` resulting in `wmic.exe` not found anymore without using its fully qualified file name. I suppose that this is the case on the machines of some users and not a missing file `wmic.exe`.

Comment: The wmic command is being depreciated, so maybe not a great approach anymore...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic